Setting up the y-axis when plotting in Python
I'm plotting in python using matplotlib. The default setting is:
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci')

I need it, but it is necessary that the multiplication be opposite each digit that is displayed along the y-axis. Like on a picture:
 ---->


The answer from @Ffisegydd still works for me with python 3.11.7. He uses import matplotlib.ticker as mtick and ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.2e')). Replace .2e by anything you like (see format documentation). This would give you something like this
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

x = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
y = np.linspace(0,1e6,1000)

fig = plt.figure(clear='True')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.2e'))
ax.plot(x,y)



